# What is the consequence to living life with self realism behavior?

Tags: self, liberation, awareness

It is very typical to live life with self realism behavior and aware every time with our daily routine. When i sit and think about my past life i just found, there was a time which has been gone and never will come back, things has been happening and passing from our eyes, we are just going, going and keep continuing. I am just feeling sad about passing time, where am i going and where will i reach. We just follow daily routines as per humanity following. I  want to know what should we our work, which could give us a full flicit and after following that way, there should not be any sadness and should be full of awareness.

Comment: This is a good question but I don't understand the phase, "self realism behavior" or "self realism"?

Answer (score 3):

Any seed's highest behaviour is to blossom into a full-fledged state which is fruit, flower etc similarly Humans can be full-fledged beings which are in the state of Blissfulness and other pleasant states if he/she gives proper attention to achieve this.

I must tell you this when you are thinking about the past there is only one moment which the moment we are living now there is no other moment cause past and future are just a phrase one can never go to future (and yes we should prepare for future) or the past so it's just in our mind only.

If you are aware enough then there should not be any thoughts come into your mind about sadness you just feel joyful about being alive. Most of the humans unconsciously think they are immortal but once you know or understand that you are mortal, you will do things only which are precious or important to you in life.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good question that you asked @singhindolia. You and I and every one and everything that exists within time and space go through five stages in life. This is inevitable. This is certain to happen and unavoidable. For example, a seed germinates and starts a bud; this is the arising stage. Then it grows to a healthy young tree; this is the growing stage where there are no flowers or fruits yet. Then comes the  optimum stage where the tree is flourishing and is full of flowers and fruits. But then with time, the tree will give less fruits and is on the way down; this is the  decaying stage where it can come down with various diseases too. This process continues until it dies.

It is no different for you and me. A human or animal will go through the same process. A human life starts not as a baby but a single cell in the womb; from there to a baby of couple of years is the arising stage. Then comes the growth stage until about 15 years or so. Life peaks from there to about 30-35 years, and that is the time one really enjoys life, the optimum stage. But then inevitably, the decay process starts and one starts feeling aches and pains, diseases, etc in the middle ages. This stage is continued in the final stage leading to death.

This is the underlying nature of this anything in this world, and that is why it is anicca: no matter how much we try, we will not be able to maintain anything to our satisfaction over long times. Thus we can see how  suffering arises due to the transient nature of our lives, which in turn leads to the conclusion that one is truly helpless (anatta) in this samsaric journey. If one truly understands this fact, that itself leads to the Stream Entrant stage of Nibbana.

Comment: Yes and I pretty much like your answer, what you call as anatta we say it "anahata" in India which is one chakra(wheel) I guess that's what you are referring to!!?

Comment: @Nisarg,  if you assume that “anatta” is the same as “anäthma” which is a Sanskrit word, it gives a totally different meaning. (as “self”). Buddha has said,”Sabbe Dhamma anatta“. So, what does “all dhamma are “no-self”” mean? Dhamma includes everything, that means inert things too. Does it make sense to say, “a tree has “no-self”? On the other hand, nothing in this world is of any real substance in the end; they all come into being and are destroyed in the end: and that is anatta. Also it is said six  internal senses are Anatta. It is meaningless to say a 'headache' has no self. - with metta.

Answer (score 1):

We should follow daily routines which will lead to a no daily routine. That is following the Noble Eightfold Path.